# Do cockpit panels have an indication that oxygen masks in cabin have been deployed?

Tags: oxygen-mask

Do cockpit panels have an indication that oxygen masks in cabin have been deployed for Pilot information?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, there is an indicator for passenger oxygen status.

[image: B737 Passenger Oxygen]
<sup>(Image Source: www.b737.org.uk)</sup>

Comment: That panel looks like it has just been bolted on as an after thought.. Was a different display there before hand?

Comment: @superphonic: All the panels look like that!

Comment: @superphonic: Perhaps overlays with different languages. Only the text is bolted on.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Seems plausible.

Answer (score 11):

In addition to [SentryRaven answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/21906/572), this is the same for Airbus (A320):

[image: A320 FCOM Panel]
(source: [FCOM A320](http://www.smartcockpit.com/docs/A320-Oxygen.pdf) at SmartCockpit.com)