# How do the oxygen masks deploy after a cabin decompression?

Tags: oxygen

Is there any sensor incorporated on the Passenger Service Unit that tells the masks to deploy when a cabin decompression occurs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.airliners.net/aviation-forums/tech_ops/read.main/291546/) Airliners.net forum post,

> The masks are deployed automatically (typically when cabin altitude exceeds 14,000 feet), or can be deployed manually from the flight deck. In addition, if a passenger service unit oxygen door should fail to open, cabin crew can open the PSU door (either inserting a flat object or a special tool depending on the aircraft type) manually.

So basically, the masks are deployed automatically based on sensors, with manual deployment as a primary failsafe and physical access as a secondary failsafe.

Comment: For completeness, many types have a manual override in the cockpit should the automatic deployment fail for whatever reason.  Examples can be seen in the [answers to this question.](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/21904/do-cockpit-panels-have-an-indication-that-oxygen-masks-in-cabin-have-been-deploy)